# Odoo: display model's fields names

Tags: orm, odoo, odoo-10

How to programmatically display a model's fields names? (let us say the model `res.partner`)

I know I can check them manually by activating the developer mode, but I need to list them programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
env["res.partner"].fields_get()
```

It returns a `dict()` with all details in a very usable format. It includes things such as the field name in the user's language, or possible selections for `Selection` fields.

Depending on your use, it can be more handy than just `._fields`.

Answer (score 3):

```
self.env['res.partner']._fields
```